# Visual Studio 2010 Debug Visualizer for boost uuid

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, boost

There are Debug Visualizers for Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 on this link http://cppvisualizers.codeplex.com/.

There are Debug Visualizers for Visual Studio 2010 on this link https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost_docs/subprojects/DebuggerVisualizers/

As you can see there is no Debug Visualizer defined for boost::uuids:uuid for Visual Studio 2010.

I am working on Visual Studio 2010 so how can i define debug visualizer for boost uuid on Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers) lists how to do it in VisualStudion 2010. It is described in setion **Native C++ Debugger Visualizers for MSVS 2005 / 2008 / 2010**.